# How to organize an audio analyzer application - activities, sound analysis?

Tags: android, audio, android-activity, audio-capture

I have an Audio analyzer app that was exported from processing.org to Android.

It works, but it's not organized properly to extend its functionalities. Therefore, I'd like to start coding proper Android app with activities and everything needed from scratch and include existing code where needed.

But I have a problem, how to organize such app in proper Android way.
Quick description of app :
- app captures sound from microphone in frames and calculates magnitude spectrum of the frame
- app supports 3 possible graphs (time-domain, spectrum and spectrogram)
- app has 4 screens - fist screen displays all 3 smaller graphs and then user can touch each graph to get into separate screen with bigger screen

I get that those screens are probably separate activities under Android (4 of them), but I'm not sure how to use audio capture and analysis code that is basically active in background and serves data to be displayed to all activities ?

If you can give me an advice or pointer to some similar examples where I can learn about it.

Thanks in advance,
regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 0):

Hello)I suppose that the best practice to organize such structure will be one activity and fragments inside of them. 
For instance: one FragmentActivity hosts your fragments and displays them together. When you press on your layouts with fragments - you go for details to another fullscreen fragment. 
To use background process you have to implement services - just like in any music app. About communication of services with activities you can real below:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html
Here you can read about fragments:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html